# How do I get this snippet of Swift code to receive the returned values from PHP script?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am running a short Swift script to post some variables a PHP script and then read the returned value:

```
  let myUrl = URL(string: "http://www.quasisquest.uk/KeepScore/createCommunity.php");

    var request = URLRequest(url:myUrl!);
    request.httpMethod = "POST";

    let postString = "communityname=\(communityName!)&code=\(communityCode)&email=\(myEmail!)";

    request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8);

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in

    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? [String:AnyObject]

           print (json["code"]);
           print (json["email"]);
           print (json["communityname"]);


        }
        task.resume()
    }
```

In my PHP code below I simply want to receive the values, and then return them in an array:

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);


require("Conn.php");
require("MySQLDao.php");

$email = htmlentities($_POST["email"]);
$code = htmlentities($_POST["code"]);
$communityname = htmlentities($_POST["communityname"]);

$returnValue = array();

$returnValue["code"] = $code;
$returnValue["email"] = $email;
$returnValue["communityname"] = $communityname;

echo json_encode($returnValue);

?>
```

I know I am doing something wrong at the end of the Swift code but I don't know what.

I am getting this error for the `let task` line:

`Invalid conversion from throwing function of type '(Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) throws -> ()' to non-throwing function type '(Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void'`

Comment: Short of running it myself, is there an error? Breakpoint "json", right click, dump, see if your data is there. Also, off topic, but if you're doing php, I'd suggest a framework, such as cakephp.

Comment: Also you'll need to unwrap those Optionals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you did not include all your code, but... are you calling `task.resume()`?

Try this:

```
let myUrl = URL(string: "http://www.quasisquest.uk/KeepScore/createCommunity.php");
var request = URLRequest(url:myUrl!);
request.httpMethod = "POST";

let postString = "communityname=\(communityName!)&code=\(communityCode)&email=\(myEmail!)";
request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8);

let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
    if let json = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? [String:AnyObject] {
        print (json["code"]);
        print (json["email"]);
        print (json["communityname"]);
    }
}

task.resume()
```

Comment: I wasn't, because when I put that in it threw out an error.  I have updated the code above with task.resume() in and the error message I am getting, thanks.

Comment: /Users/richdowns/Desktop/One More Round/KeepScore/KeepScore/CreateNewCommunity.swift:65:66: Invalid conversion from throwing function of type '(Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) throws -> ()' to non-throwing function type '(Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void'

Comment: I took out the 3x let commands and it just about worked - printing out this:Optional(S7LJEA)
Optional(Optional(&quot;sam.bawdry@gmail.com&quot;))
Optional(Optional(&quot;testing&quot;))   why is it printing '&quot' though?

Comment: I'd check the data sent from the sever itself in that case.

Comment: sussed it. It just needed ! on the end of each object in the postString line